# why does Element::getElementsByTagNameNS fail?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Given the XML instance document:

```
<foo:A xmlns:foo="http://foo" >
    <foo:ListRecords>
        <foo:record>
        </foo:record>
    </foo:ListRecords>
</foo:A>
```

The following code:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;


public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new File("record.xml"));
        Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList records1 = rootElement.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "record");
        NodeList records2 = rootElement.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://foo", "record");
        NodeList records3 = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("foo:record");
        System.out.printf("%d records1 found.\n", records1.getLength());
        System.out.printf("%d records2 found.\n", records2.getLength());
        System.out.printf("%d records3 found.\n", records3.getLength());
    }
}
```

prints:

```
0 records1 found.
0 records2 found.
1 records3 found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a namespace-aware parser. [By default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29), JDK parsers are not namespace aware.

Change your code to look like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```